# Find the number of ways that 9 students can take 3 different tests if 3 students are to take each test.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There are 9 students in a class. Find the number of ways the 9 students can take 3 different tests if 3 students are to take each test.

Confused on how this would be set up.

Comment: Hint:  Select which students take the first test.  Select which of the remaining students take the second test.  The remaining students must take the third test.

Answer (score 3):

First choose the three students to take the first test.  How many ways to select them?  Then choose the students to take the second test out of the ones remaining.  How many ways?  The others take the third test.

Answer (score 0):

Call each test Test A, Test B, and Test C. Then there are $_9C_3$ or "9 choose 3" ways of picking the three students that will receive test A. Then there are 6 students without a test, and there will be $_6C_3$ ways of choosing which students receive test B. The 3 remaining students will receive test C. This means that there are $_9C_3*_6C_3$ ways of dealing out the tests. By the formula for $_mC_n$, this is equal to
$$\frac{9!}{3!6!}*\frac{6!}{3!3!}$$
$$\frac{7*8*9}{3*2}*\frac{4*5*6}{3*2}$$
$$7*3*4*2*2*5$$
$$7*3*4*2*2*5$$
$$1680$$
So there are a total of $1680$ ways to do this.

Comment: Thing is there are answer choices... A:9! B: 3! C:9!/3! D: 3 ways

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Comment: Its on a take homework sheet that my professor assigned..

Comment: Either it has a mistake or I'm making some blatantly obvious error. This problem can even be easily solved by the "partitions" formula that gives the number of ways in which $9$ students can be divided into $3$ groups of $3$, which also gives an answer of $1680$.

Answer (score 0):

Total ways 9 students can take 9 distinct tests = 9!

How many of these ways are the same?

There are 3 groups of 3. In a given group of 3, there are 3! ways to sort students.

I think you can take it from here.